# Implicit Function Thm

Tags: implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem, implicit-function

How do I apply the implicit function theorm to

$$f(x,y,z)= \begin{bmatrix}(x-1)^2+y^2+z^2\\ (x+1)^2+y^2+z^2\end{bmatrix}$$

at the point $(0,0,1)$???
I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. I've tried to do $\begin{bmatrix}(f_1)_y &(f_1)_z\\ (f_2)_y& (f_2)_z\end{bmatrix}$ and got $\begin{bmatrix}2y &2z\\2y &2z\end{bmatrix}$ but that doesn't seem right and even if it is right, I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE!  You can find math formatting requirements [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: So what do you know about the Implicit function theorem?  What is it for, and what exactly does it say?

Comment: just for my own knowledge @RobertTheTutor is this where $z$ is made to be the chart? we take $z=1$?

Answer (score 1):

Given $f(x,y,z) = \begin{bmatrix}{(x-1)}^2 + y^2 + z^2 \\ {(x+1)}^2 + y^2 + z^2 \end{bmatrix}$, we need to expand the definition to get a square matrix, thus:

$f(x,y,z) = \begin{bmatrix}{(x-1)}^2 + y^2 + z^2 \\ {(x+1)}^2 + y^2 + z^2 \\ z \end{bmatrix}$ and
$Df = \begin{bmatrix} 2x-2 & 2y & 2z \\ 2x+2 & 2y & 2z \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$
and $Df(0,0,1) = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 0 & 2 \\ 2 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

The implicit function theorem in regular calculus says that $${(f^{-1})}^{'}(b) = \frac{1}{f^{'}(a)}$$
where $f(a) = b$.
I was going to extend this definition to a $3x3$ matrix, but unfortunately that matrix is not invertible!